# Как сделать проверку наличия директивы Host в robots.txt

Tags: php, seo

Привет!Я начал изучать то как работают поисковые роботы яндекса и мне по заданию нужно сделать проверку на наличие директивы Host в файле robots.txt.Но я не понимаю как это сделать.Можете показать на примере как правильноэто сделать?

Comment: А что там проверять ? в robots.txt установите Host: www.vashsite.ru и всё. Для проверки можете воспользоваться инструментом "Проверка Robots.txt" в кабинете  Яндекс Вебмастера

Comment: Я думаю тс хочет парсить файл robots.txt и проверять наличие в нем строки с host. рекомендую просто загуглить  "парсинг файла php" и внимательно почитать пару первых ссылок  примеров масса

Comment: директива Host в файле robots.txt в яндексе уже отменена, задание у вас какое-то ..................